# Why is Eleventy looking for templates in my /history folder?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

For some reason Eleventy is looking for templates in my /history folder, which I have already made changes to. Is there a way to stop this?

Now when I run my build the following error occurs:

```
[11ty] 2. (./.history/_includes/layouts/base_20220423223526.njk)
[11ty]   Error: template not found: partials/navigation.njk (via Template render error)
[11ty] 
[11ty] Original error stack trace: Template render error: (./.history/_includes/layouts/base_20220423223526.njk)
[11ty]   Error: template not found: partials/navigation.njk
```

Here is my repo if you would like to have a look:
https://github.com/dulzorigo/eleventy-tailwind

Forked from:
https://github.com/ThirusOfficial/eleventy-tailwind

Answer (score 0):

By default, Eleventy processes all files in your provided input folder, which is the root of your project in this case. To have Eleventy ignore certain folders or files, you can create an `.eleventyignore` file containing `.history`. See [the Eleventy documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/ignores/) for more information.